# How to assign feature and target names to graph a decision tree in python?

Tags: python-3.x, graph, error-handling, scikit-learn, graphviz

I am using some data from a sample `s` I import (`.dta` file) to python 3. I do some machine learning analysis. I came across this neat way to plot decisions trees produced with `scikit-learn` and `graphviz`.

Here is what I do (next to some package and library imports etc.):

```
#   import data and give a little overview
sample = pd.read_stata('sample_data.dta')
s = sample

#   some learning
X = np.array((s.X).reshape(100, 1))
y = np.array(s.y)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = tts(X, y, test_size = .8)

my_tree = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = my_tree.fit(X_train, y_train)

from IPython.display import Image  
dot_data = StringIO()  
tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=dot_data,  
    feature_names=s.feature_names,  
    class_names=s.target_names,  
    filled=True, rounded=True,  
    special_characters=True)  
graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())  
Image(graph.create_png())
```

Everything works well untill I want to graph the tree. I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'feature_names'
```

How do I assign `feature_names` to `s`?

Comment: `feature_names` must be a list of column names from `s` you want to use as features and `target_names` should be the column you want to perform the classification agains't.

Comment: Cool, that's what I thought. But how to I assign a list of column names?

Comment: Let's suppose you have `C1` → `C5` as your columns in the `dataframe` and `C5` is the target categorical variable having 3 distinct categories/classes [A, B, C].Then, `feature_names` = `['C1',...,'C4']` and `target_names` = `['A', 'B', 'C']`, which later becomes your `class_names` assuming you want to use `C1` → `C4` as your features.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! That already helped. I managed to produce 'tree.png' - yet I can't open it somehow. Is there something else I need to do?